# Nifi: How to write sub/nested element in JSON

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have an incoming Nifi flowfile that looks like this

```
{"filename":"ok.txt.2018-01-27-16-18-03-290","test":"{\"filename\":ok.txt,\"test\":23}","timestamp":"Sat Jan 27 16:18:03 UTC 2018"}
```

I want to add a sub/nested element "test": { "text":"Hello world","Country":"Espana"} to the "test" element. In other words, I want my JSON output looking like

```
{"filename":"ok.txt.2018-01-27-16-18-03-290","test":"{\"filename\":ok.txt,\"test\":23, "text": {"Hello world","Country":"Espana"}}","timestamp":"Sat Jan 27 16:18:03 UTC 2018"}
```

Is it possible to add subelement to a JSON in Nifi?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ExecuteGroovyScript 1.5.0` processor with the following code

```
import groovy.json.*

def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

ff.write{rawIn,rawOut->
    //parse json from input stream of the flow file
    def json = rawIn.withReader("UTF-8"){reader-> 
        new JsonSlurper().parse( reader )
    }
    //modify json 
    json."test" = [
            "text"     :"Hello world",
            "Country"  :"Espana"
        ]
    //write json to flow file output stream
    rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){writer->
        new JsonBuilder(json).writeTo(writer)
    }
}

REL_SUCCESS << ff
```